# Disable LAN Access without disabling WAN on a Hyper V VM

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, local-area-network, windows-server-2019, wide-area-network

I have a Hyper V virtual machine running on windows server 2019 that will be used to run a guest OS (Windows 10). How do I allow access to the internet, but block it from accessing LAN, network shared folders, printers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A Private VLAN can be used to create an environment where VMs may only interact with the Internet and not have visibility into other VMs’ network traffic.  To accomplish this put all VMs (actually their Hyper-V switch ports) into the same PVLAN in isolated mode."

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj679878(v=ws.11)